# validate claims inside JWT using envoy

Tags: authentication, jwt, microservices, envoyproxy, servicemesh

```
{
  "aud": "123123-1232-123123-2323-123",
  "iss": "https://url",
  "iat": 2112,
  "nbf": 1212,
  "exp": 1212,
  "aio": "ewq32ee23e2e=",
  "azp": "123123-1232-123123-2323-123",
  "azpacr": "1",
  "oid": "123123-1232-123123-2323-123",
  "rh": "1.qqfn4wanflwf3aldAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "sub": "123123-1232-123123-2323-123"
}
```

My JWT contains the above claims. i have to validate 3 things

1. audience : aud
2. issuer : iss
3. roles : 'roles' should be present in JWT. Its value array should contain 'default'. How can this be achieved with envoy?

I researched a bit and found a way to validate audience 'aud' and issuer 'iss'.

```
  http_filters:
    - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
      typed_config: 
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication
        providers:
          "auth-iam":
            issuer: https://url
            forward: true,
            audiences:
            - 123123-1232-123123-2323-123  # [audience]
            remote_jwks:
              http_uri:  # [3]
                uri: https://url/keys # [simple]
                cluster: auth-iam
                timeout: 5s
              cache_duration:
                seconds: 900                        
        rules:  
          - match:
              prefix: /actuator/health
          - match:
              prefix: /
            requires:
              provider_name: auth-iam
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to acheive the above by adddding a lua filter and writing a lua script to validate token claims. it works in these 2 steps :

1. add the payload from JWT to a variable **jwt_payload**.

   ```
   - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
     typed_config:
       "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication
       providers:
         "auth-iam":
           issuer: https://url,
           forward: true
           audiences:
           - 123123-1232-123123-2323-123
           remote_jwks:
             http_uri:
               uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
               cluster: auth-iam
               timeout: 5s
             cache_duration:
               seconds: 900
           payload_in_metadata: jwt_payload
           rules: 
             - match:
                 prefix: /health
             - match:
                 prefix: /
               requires:
                 provider_name: auth-iam
   ```
2. retreive the payload and write custom logic to validate the token claims. the filter would be added just above `- name: envoy.filters.http.router`

   ```
   - name: envoy.filters.http.lua
     typed_config:
       "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
       inline_code: |
         function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
           local meta = request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata()
           for key, value in pairs(meta) do
             -- request_handle:logInfo("extract dynamicMetadata key: "..key)
             -- request_handle:logInfo("extract dynamicMetadata value: "..value.jwt_payload.roles[1])
             if(value.jwt_payload.roles == nil or value.jwt_payload.roles[1] ~= "default")
             then
               request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "403",},"JWT validation failed.") 
             end
           end
         end
   ```